# How are the sub-periods derrived in TWRR Daily Valuation?

Tags: investing, calculation, portfolio, rate-of-return

I've been looking at the [TWRR Daily Valuation](http://www.dailyvest.com/PRR/prr_calcmethods.aspx#twrr-dailyval) method and I'm trying to understand how to break the total performance period into sub-periods when there are irregular cash flows.

As the article explains:

> The Daily Valuation Method breaks the total performance period into
>   sub-periods, the boundaries of which are based on the occurrence of
>   cash flows.

In particular they show the following example:
[image]

In the case that I'm trying to apply the formula, there are multiple cash flows whose size and occurrence are at irregular periods:

- Deposits (in)
- Withdrawals (out)
- Loan received (in)
- Loan payments (out)
- Investments (out)
- Returns on investments (in)

**The formula implies that the periods are not uniform, but irregular and dependent on the time of the cash flow. If the periods are based on the cash flows, then how does one handle multiple cash flows per day?**

Comment: It depends on how granular you want to be but summing the cash flows within a given day would be a reasonable approach.

Comment: Thanks @assylias the more I'm looking at it, the more it seems like that's the best approach too. I'm not a finance guys, so this is all kinda new to me and I'm just trying to make sense of it. :)